# Zoom h4n Crunchy Sound on Windows 10

Tags: windows, audio

Issue: I'm using a zoom h4n as an external sound card on windows 10, both for microphone input and headphone output. I know this is overkill but I have it, might as well use it. The issue is that on windows 10 plugging it in and using it as a sound card makes all audio played through it 'crunchy', like there is digital clipping. This happens despite turning down the output volume in the application, in windows, or on the h4n itself. This problem does not happen when using this device in the same role connected to a mac.

Answer (score 0):

Answer: After some experimentation I found a solution. In windows I went to sound settings -> Headphones (H4) -> Device properties (edit for newer versions of windows 10: this is now called Additional device properties). In the properties screen there is an advanced tab and in the advanced tab there is a default format setting. This was set for me to 2 channel, 16 bit, 48000 Hz. I changed it to 2 channel, 16 bit, 44100 Hz which is the default mode when connecting the h4n as an external sound card. This caused the clipping to go away.